# the keyboard not show in eclipse emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I am new to android , I've downloaded the latest version of Eclipse and when I use the edittext, the keypad is not visible, what shall I do??

and this is the result in emulator

[image]

[image]

and this the setting of emulator

Answer (score 0):

The keyboard will not pop up if you are emulating a device with a hardware keyboard.

Goto AVD, select your AVD name and click edit. Edit Android Virtual Device dialog will appear. You can verify this

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are emulating a device which has a hardware keyboard.

You can still use your system keyboard to type data into the EditText on the Emulator for testing purposes.

But if you really want to show the keyboard when you click the EditText, you would need to emulate a device which supports only a soft keyboard. Or otherwise, go to AVD Manager in Eclipse and select your the virtual device that you created. Edit AVD and remove hardware keyboard from the properties of the AVD. That way your emulator would be configured only to support a soft keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Just Check it once in AVD Configuration (Goto ->Windows->AVD manager-->Select AVD-->Edit )whether that Hardware Keyboard is checked or not.if it's not checked that it woudn't come.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you have enabled the option for hardware keyboard, you can only see the keyboard if you enabled soft keyboard for you AVD, you can use you physical keyboard for interaction or edit your AVD